# MaxMin diversity selection with RDKit

Tags: algorithm, sampling, rdkit, cheminformatics

I cannot find a detailed exposition of the Leader algorithm used to perform MaxMin diversity picking. The documentation (https://www.rdkit.org/docs/source/rdkit.SimDivFilters.rdSimDivPickers.html) leads to this other link: https://www.nextmovesoftware.com/talks/Sayle_2DSimilarityDiversityAndClusteringInRdkit_RDKITUGM_201909.pdf, but there's only one slide on the more efficient algorithm. Can anyone please hepl with the details?

This post (http://rdkit.blogspot.com/2017/11/revisting-maxminpicker.html) has some info about a previous Lazy picker, but nothing about the Leader algorithm